# Is How To Geek no longer part of the 'League of Justice'?

Tags: discussion, league-of-justice, howtogeek

The link on the bottom of the site is no longer there.  It has been replaced by the Area 51 link.

Does this mean that [How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/about/) is gone from the 'League of Justice'?

Comment: HTG is still linking to the trilogy though.

Comment: And he is still a mod in SU. (With almost no activity)

Comment: [His site](http://www.howtogeek.com/) is definitely still active.

Comment: HTG just started to work for himself and is currently working on improving his own 'trilogy'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't read too much into it... it's simply a space issue - Jeff needed room to link up more of the Stackoverflow sites, so he had to remove the link.

And yes, I'm rather busy and don't have time to mod anything anywhere =)

Comment: sorry, I meant to respond as well -- I did email The Geek when I took it off, and explained why. No bad blood, we're still pals and are actively looking for ways to promote SU and HTG together.

Comment: @Jeff @The I agree that at the time (6 months ago) there wasn't enough space, but now that we have 3 rows of SE sites listed that doesn't seem as huge an issue. There's 28 links down there now, would one more to How To Geek hurt? Or is that space now reserved for SE sites only? :D