# Where is the link to howtogeek

Tags: discussion, league-of-justice, howtogeek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is How To Geek no longer part of the ‘League of Justice’?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55668/is-how-to-geek-no-longer-part-of-the-league-of-justice)

I noticed that there is nowadays no link to howtogeek anymore [(remember League of Justice?)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/howtogeek-and-stack-overflow/) Where / when / why did it disappear?

Comment: related is the new **exact duplicate**?

Comment: I also voted to close myself. I didn't find that question with the term howtogeek.

Comment: no prob @Peter, we only found it because we read it a few days ago