# Why does Careers have a different footer than the rest of the trilogy?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, jobs, footer

The [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) footer included a link for the How To Geek, but not a link to Area 51.

Every other site (Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Meta) has the link to Area 51, and no link for How To Geek.

Why is there a discrepancy?

Comment: Because they are two completely different websites?

Comment: Because it wasn't updated when the others were?

Comment: Why do you care?

Answer (score 2):

We've updated it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a new thing, since I'm not seeing the How To Geek link on anything anymore. I suspect this was removed from all of the footers.

Comment: Twas removed, indeed. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55668/is-how-to-geek-no-longer-part-of-the-league-of-justice